# angular material dialog imports probleme

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Good morning,

I want to display the dialog of angular material but I have a problem with the imports I do not understand the problem.

and of course I have an angular material module where I imported matdialog and I imported that in app.module

errors : **ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type DialogFormComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and ProduitsModule!**

**app.module**

```
import { DialogFormComponent } from './produits/dialog-form/dialog-form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogFormComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [DialogFormComponent],
```

**produits.ts**

```
export class ProduitsComponent implements OnInit {

  public productArray: Produit[] = [];

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(DialogFormComponent);
  }

}
```

Comment: The error says you have declared `DialogFormComponent` in 2 different modules. Have you? If yes, correct that. Seems clear enough.

Comment: And if you don't define the entry component, does it works ?

Comment: Is your `ProduitsModule` [lazily loaded](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)? You can tell by looking in your `app-routing.module`

Comment: @Tino yes is lazy loaded  the entry component is produits component no ?

Comment: the latest version of angular can work without entry components, remove the import from the app module

Comment: @FaizalHussain I tried to remove all the imports in app.module but it still doesn't work

Comment: can u add a stackblitz demo ?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution in fact I have a produits.module where was declared the dialogFormComponent I deleted it now everything works thanks to your help